# PHP Function, Takes 2 Paramenters, JSON String and Date String and Returns JSON String

Tags: php, json, string, decode, encode

I am working over a PHP problem to Write a function that takes in two parameters: 1) a json string which contains articles 2) a string date in the format "2015-09-04" The function should return a json string of articles which were published in the two weeks prior to the given date.  But am getting " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\phpExercisesW3\index.php on line 94 "

```
<?php  
        $json = '[
            {
                "title": "This is the first title",
                "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                "date": "2015-07-30"
            },
            {
                "title": "Another article",
                "body": "Quisqu porttitor dignissim massa rhoncus imperdiet.",
                "date": "2015-08-18"
            },
            {
                "title": "The Final Title",
                "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
                "date": "2015-08-30"
            },
        ]';    

        $date = "2015-09-04";

        function returnTwoWeeksPrior($jsonString, $dateString) {
            $decode = json_decode($jsonString);
            forEach($decode as $decoded) {
                if ($decode->date < strtotime('-2 weeks')) {
                    $result = json_encode($decoded);
                    echo $result;
                } else {
                    echo "No articles found.";
                }
            }
        }

        echo returnTwoWeeksPrior($json, $date);

        ?>
```

Comment: There is an error in your json. You have to remove your last `,`

Comment: `var_dump($decode);` and `echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: `$decoded` not `$decode`

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

- trailing coma on your json
- your if was trying to access date on $decode which is the array, you should use $decoded->date
- also, you were comparing a string ($decoded->date) and an int (strtotime('-2 weeks'))

Here is your code working.

```
    <?php  
    $json = '[
        {
            "title": "This is the first title",
            "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
            "date": "2015-07-30"
        },
        {
            "title": "Another article",
            "body": "Quisqu porttitor dignissim massa rhoncus imperdiet.",
            "date": "2015-08-18"
        },
        {
            "title": "The Final Title",
            "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
            "date": "2015-08-30"
        }
    ]';    

    $date = "2015-09-04";

   function returnTwoWeeksPrior($jsonString, $dateString) {
        $decode = json_decode($jsonString);
        $results = [];
        forEach($decode as $decoded) {
            if (strtotime($decoded->date) < (strtotime($dateString.'-2 weeks')) ) {
                $result = json_encode($decoded);
                echo $result;
                $results[] = $result;
            } 
        }
        if(count($results) == 0){
            echo "No articles found.";
        }
    }

    echo returnTwoWeeksPrior($json, $date);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Now the error i get is Trying to get property 'date' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\phpExercisesW3\index.php on line 95. Why is it telling me $decode is a non-object? I decoded it turned it into an object with my code of "$decode = json_decode($jsonString);"

Comment: Thanks. However, the output with this code returns all three articles and it should only return the final Title object since that is the only article with a date within the last two weeks of 2015-09-04

Comment: indeed, I just read the code and assumed it was 2 weeks ago from the current date, not it's using the given time. I've also made some changes to print results no found only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.  Why?

See these lines:

```
    {
        "title": "The Final Title",
        "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
        "date": "2015-08-30"
    },
]';
```

You have an extra ',' that needs to be removed for it to be a valid array.

Should be:

```
{
    "title": "The Final Title",
    "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
    "date": "2015-08-30"
}
```

]';

Your first move with a problem like this is to var_dump() or var_export() your expected variable.  Doing this with your $decode variable would have shown you that it was null.

There are tools like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) that can help you in the future with these types of issues, but at the end of the day, the chrome console is always great when dealing with javascript.

**Other bugs**

You have a bug in your code where instead of referencing the variable you create in your foreach loop, you attempt to reference the original array of objects.

See:

```
if ($decode->date < strtotime('-2 weeks')) {
```

Should be

```
if ($decoded->date < strtotime('-2 weeks')) {
```

Here the PHP error is quite helpful:

> Trying to get property 'date' of non-object

Right away, you should focus in on the fact that your code is referencing a "non-object" and question why that might be.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  Now the error i get is Trying to get property 'date' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\phpExercisesW3\index.php on line 95.  Why is it telling me $decode is a non-object? I decoded it turned it into an object with my code of  "$decode = json_decode($jsonString);"

Comment: Thanks. The other answers give me all three articles back but two weeks from my $date variable should only return the The Final Article.

Comment: Your actual date comparison has a number of issues including the fact that your comparison needs to be > rather than <.  [Working version is here](https://3v4l.org/OJi80).

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<?php  
        $json = '[
            {
                "title": "This is the first title",
                "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                "date": "2015-07-30"
            },
            {
                "title": "Another article",
                "body": "Quisqu porttitor dignissim massa rhoncus imperdiet.",
                "date": "2015-08-18"
            },
            {
                "title": "The Final Title",
                "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
                "date": "2015-08-30"
            }
        ]';    

        $date = "2015-09-04";

        function returnTwoWeeksPrior($jsonString, $dateString) {
            $decode = json_decode($jsonString);
            forEach($decode as $decoded) {
                if (strtotime($decoded->date) < strtotime('-2 weeks', strtotime($date))) {
                    $result = json_encode($decoded);
                    echo $result;
                } else {
                    echo "No articles found.";
                }
            }
        }

        echo returnTwoWeeksPrior($json, $date);

        ?>
```

First of all your JSON is invalid: there is a trailing comma init, and you're trying to compare a string with a number, and you messed up `$decoded` and `$decode`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, My the output with this code returns everything and it should only return the final Title object since that is the only article with a date within the last two weeks of 2015-09-04

Answer (score 0):

your json should like below

```
$json = '{
            "items" :[
            {
                "title": "This is the first title",
                "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                "date": "2015-07-30"
            },
            {
                "title": "Another article",
                "body": "Quisqu porttitor dignissim massa rhoncus imperdiet.",
                "date": "2015-08-18"
            },
            {
                "title": "The Final Title",
                "body": "In aliquam auctor ex quis consequat. Praesent non lobortis metus.",
                "date": "2015-08-30"
            }
            ]
        }';
```

you shoudn't use the

```
,
```

after your last item in list